# make 2 navigations centered when width is limited using flexbox only

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 2 `nav`s on the same line. One is on the left, the other is on the right.

When space is scarce, I'd like to make both of navigations **centered** and take full width of the container.

Take a look at an example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxeoeK

html:

```
<div class="nav-mixed">
  <nav class="first">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
   <nav class="second">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

css:

```
body{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.nav-mixed{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
nav{
  background-color:grey;
  width:600px
}
```

This is easy using @media queries, but I'd like to use flexbox only as a solution.

What do you recommend?

Comment: centred and full width means full width, centred is useless in this case

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
body{
      background-color:yellow;
    }
    .nav-mixed{
      display:flex;
      flex-wrap:wrap;
      justify-content:space-around;
    }
    nav{
      background-color:grey;
      width:600px;
        flex:0 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="nav-mixed">
  <nav class="first">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
   <nav class="second">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Updated space-between to space-around and added flex:0 0 auto; on nav

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. This is one solution. I'd also wanted for both of the navs to take full width, once the break occurs.